# Why does this anchor tag not load to the appropriate div on an external page?

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile, anchor

Can anyone tell me why my anchor tags do not work? They simply load the external page but do not bring you to the correct div down the page.

This is the code on my .php page

```
</td><td class="shorter"> 
<input name="txt2nd" class="numbersOnly" type="number" id="txt2nd"></td>
<td class="shortest">
<a href="update.html#update_show" rel="external" id="update"><img class="update" alt="update price" src="images/update.png">
</a></td>
</tr>
```

Which should then load an external page at the point of the anchor id. This is what the code on that page looks like:

```
<div class="text-bg">
  <form method="post" data-ajax="false" id="update_show" action="php/input_shows.php">
      <p><label for="name">Your name</label><input type="text" size="30" name="name" id="name" /></p>
      <p><label for="price">Price of a show</label><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="price" id="price" cols="5" /></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Update" name="commit" id="message_submit"/> or 
      <a  rel="external" href="budget.html">Cancel</a></p>
  </form>
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or if this caused by some conflict with jQuery mobile I am not aware of. I'm hoping you guys will notice something really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the external page you need an anchor tag for it to link to, not any element with an id.  `<a name="update_show"></a>` just above the form.

**Update**:
As suggested by @Marko D you don't need the named anchor tag.  I would make an assumption that it doesn't work due to JS.

Comment: That does work, I must have another issue with my page due to the jQuery because the initial load quickly displays the correct div but half a second later takes me back to the top.
Thanks

Comment: It does sound like a problem with your JS.  Attempt with JS disabled.  You must have something that it cause a scroll to top to occur.

Comment: yes you're right, just disabled my jquery link and it works fine - but looks hideous. Thanks Ollie

Comment: I am not sure it's neccessary to create `<a name=...`, have a look at http://w3fools.com/#html_links

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I have the answer to this, which I posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553746/1462775

NOTE: This should probably just be added as a comment to the above question, but I don't have enough points yet to do that. :(